# How can I get an array of very large primes when I don't have a lot of memory?

Tags: performance-tuning, memory, prime-numbers

I would like to perform computations on an array of primes within the range $[2,10^{15}]$. For the moment, I am `select`ing such an array using the command:

```
myLimit = 10^11;
myPrimes = Select[Prime[Range[PrimePi[myLimit]]]];
```

I can get up to `myLimit`, i.e., $10^{11}$, but anything higher than that will crash my kernel because I only have $16$ GB of RAM. How can I fetch more values into my array without buying more RAM? Is there some more efficient way to do this?

Comment: You can go through the primes one by one with `Do` and append them to a list as you find them. It wouldn't be efficient, of course. The immediate problem here is that you are trying to create an enormous list up front, using `Do` would absolve you from that.

Comment: @C.E. Thank you for your comment. Could you post an example?

Comment: There are $3204941750802$ primes smaller than $10^{14}$, if you store each one as 64-bit number the total size of the array would be over 25 TB. I suggest you either lower your upper limit or change your strategy. What computations do you want to perform on those primes?

Comment: @rafalc Thank you for those figures. I would not necessarily work on *all* those primes, I would select some subset based on some criteria, for instance, primes of the type $4n+1$ or $4n+3$, or other criteria. I just wanted to work my question in the most general possible way, i.e., getting an array of large primes when one does not have sufficient RAM. I believe C.E.'s method might be what I'm looking for, if only he could post a quick  snippet.

Comment: @Klangen if RAM is your main concern, you can generate the first 1000 primes (or any number that will fit in your RAM), then export to a file, generate next 1000 primes and append to the file and so on. Then you can import only the numbers you want to process at a time. This solution will obviously have high I/O overhead.

Comment: @rafalc Your method, too, would interest me if provided with an example.